# BS4 Select() Method

Tags: python

This is my code to crawl and parse the necessary information from the wordinastence.com which provides useful context sentence for given word:

```
#first import request to crawl the html from the target page
#this case the website is http://www,wordinasentence.com

import requests

target = input("The word you want to search : ")

res = requests.get("https://wordsinasentence.com/"+ target+"-in-a-sentence/")

#further, put this in so that res_process malfunction could flag the errors
try:
    res.raise_for_status()
except Exception as e:
    print("There's a problem while connecting to a wordsinasentence sever:", e)

#it's a unreadable information, so that we needs to parse it to make it readable.
## use the beautifulsoup to make it readable

import bs4
html_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

#check it has been well parsed
#now we'll extract the Defintion of target

keywords = html_soup.select('Definition')
```

If I run the given method select('Defintion'), it keeps returning nothing as empty list even the following printed out with the **html_soup** variable :

```
<p onclick='responsiveVoice.speak("not done for any particular reason; chosen or done at random");' style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Arial; font-size:20px; color:#504A4B;padding-bottom:0px;">Definition of Arbitrary</p>

[]
```

What would be the possible problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the wrong method to find a text (`select()` is made for css selector). You could use the [keyword `string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument) with `find_all` and a function to select the tag you are looking for.

```
def has_text_def(s):    
    return s and s.startswith('Definition of')

definitions = soup.find_all('p', string=has_text_def)
```

By the way, you need to get the [next element in the tree (with `next_sibling`)](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) to access the definition :

```
for p in definitions:
    print(p.next_sibling.next_sibling.text)
```